# Calculate % Difference in Pandas and apply special conditions to results

Tags: python, pandas, csv, math

I'm new to python and trying to get % differences in users between each week starting from the oldest. So trying to calculate like this (this calculation is from Tableau, but I want python to do similar):

3to2WeeksAgo difference:

```
IF [Users3weeksAgo] != 0 THEN ([Users2weeksAgo]-[Users3weeksAgo])/[Users3weeksAgo]
END
```

input.csv:

```
id    ThisWeekUsers LastWeekUsers   Users2weeksAgo  Users3weeksAgo
 1           91              20          8               15
 2            4              1           0               0
 3            4              1           3               14
 ...
```

What I couldn't get was strictly formatted output. I need my results to show as below: Output.csv

```
id    ThisWeekUsers LastWeekUsers   Users2weeksAgo  Users3weeksAgo 3to2WeeksAgo 2toLastWeek LastToThisWeek
 1           91              20          8               15            -46.7%      150.0%         355.0%
 2            4              1           0               0                                        300.0%
 3            4              1           3               14            -78.6%      -66.7%         300.0%
 ...
```

My code so far:

```
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/input.csv')

 df['3to2WeeksAgo'] = df['Users2weeksAgo']-df['Users3weeksAgo']/df['Users3weeksAgo']


 df.to_csv('path/to/my/output.csv')
```

Also, I want to make sure there are no NaN or inf values in my output and keep format strictly as 00.0

These are the results when comparing 3 weeks ago to 2 weeks ago with the code above:

[image]

The above results should show:

```
3to2WeeksAgo
   -46.7% 

   -78.6%
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

EDIT:

Thanks for your help Kranthi! I've run this code and it seems to be working. However I have additional question. How can I prevent 0.0 from showing when comparing 0 from one week with 0 in another week. Same for 'inf' value. Could you help me getting no values for those cases?see below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/input.csv')

df['3to2WeeksAgo'] = np.round(100 * (df['Users2weeksAgo'] - df['Users3weeksAgo']) / df['Users3weeksAgo'], 1)
```

Same for `2toLastWeek`, `LastToThisWeek`

```
df = df.fillna(0)
df.to_csv('path/to/my/output.csv')
```

Comment: Might want to point out that the main issue OP hit was that they didn't wrap `df['Users2weeksAgo'] - df['Users3weeksAgo']` in brackets thus `df['Users3weeksAgo']) / df['Users3weeksAgo']` was calculated first then subtracted from `df['Users2weeksAgo']`. [Help full cheat sheet for python's order of operations.](https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html)

Comment: Hi Kranthi, thank you for your help. I have tried this, but have additional question regarding 0.0 or inf values in my results. See EDIT paragraph at the end of my initial post. Thanks!

Comment: I changed `df = df.fillna(0)` to `df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], '')` would that be it? thanks